# Having trouble replacing /**comment**/ with something else in my javascript and sql

Tags: javascript, sql, comments

I'm trying to replace a comment in my sql query using a javascript. 
My sql query goes something like this.

```
    select round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 1 and date_part('year', fd.fs_dt) = /**year**/ then amount end)::numeric, 0) January_data
from this_table
```

My javascript query goes something like this.

```
if (params["This_year"] == "1/1/14"){
this.querytext = this.queryText.replace("/**year**/", "2014")}
else if (params["This_year"] == "1/1/15"){
this.querytext = this.queryText.replace("/**year**/", "2015")}
```

It's giving me an error at or near 'then'

Comment: `this.querytext` and `this.queryText` are not the same.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol would that be causing it? If so, what would I choose, this.queryText, or this.querytext?

Comment: You've just changed your error message, and therefore the entire question.  This error is about transactions, you need to close your transaction.  Your previous error was more in line with @NiettheDarkAbsol's comment.

Comment: I changed the error, because when I changed queryText, it updated. Do you know how to close the transaction? @paqogomez

Comment: @user3613495: You should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't actually replace anything since you assign the result of the replacement to a new variable (`querytext` instead of `queryText`).

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that, and now it is giving me a new error.

Comment: Don't change the question to fix the error. Other users will come and will be confused. Revert your edit and accept my answer. Then ask a new question. Note: This isn't a discussion site. It's a one question one answer site.